# Linq To SQL with left join and sum() throws exception

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following (simplified) database tables:

```
Products
- ProductID, int, PK
- Name, varchar(50)

Orders
- OrderID, int, PK
- ProductID, int, FK
- Quantity, int, not null
```

I would like to read all products and if orders are available, sum the quantity of all orders for that product.

The SQL query would look like this:

```
select p.ProductID, p.Name, sum(o.Quantity) from Products p 
left join Orders o on p.ProductID = o.ProductID
group by p.ProductID, p.Name
```

Now, I would like to translate this in a Linq-to-SQL query.
I have come to this so far:

```
var query =
    from p in Products
    join o in Orders on p.ProductID equals o.ProductID into po
    from subOrder in po.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group subOrder by new
    {
      p.ProductID,
      p.Name,
    }
    into productGroup
    select new
    {
      productGroup.Key.ProductID,
      productGroup.Key.Name,
      Quantity = productGroup.Sum(subOrder => subOrder.Quantity)
    };
```

Although the generated SQL looks fine, I get the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The null value cannot be assigned to a
>   member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with the query. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `productGroup.Sum(subOrder => (int?)subOrder.Quantity)` instead.

Comment: For the down voter: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/368947/linq-to-sql-sum-and-nullable-values . If there aren't any `subOrder`s the sum is calculated on an empty result set and trying to assign null to int.

Comment: Thanks, this works! It returns null for all products with no orders. Although the generated SQL is not entirely as expected:`SELECT SUM([t2].[value]) AS [Quantity], [t2].[ProductID], [t2].[Name]
FROM (
    SELECT [t1].[Quantity] AS [value], [t0].[ProductID], [t0].[Name]
    FROM [Products] AS [t0]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Orders] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ProductID] = [t1].[ProductID]
    ) AS [t2]
GROUP BY [t2].[ProductID], [t2].[Name]
`

Comment: @Andreas could you translate the query using lambda (Method-Based)? there is no Left Join method, only Join

Answer (score 2):

Use it:

```
Quantity = productGroup.Sum(subOrder => (int?)subOrder.Quantity ?? 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! It returns zero for all products with no orders. Although the generated SQL is not entirely as expected:

`SELECT SUM([t2].[value]) AS [Quantity], [t2].[ProductID], [t2].[Name]
FROM (
    SELECT COALESCE([t1].[Quantity],@p0) AS [value], [t0].[ProductID], [t0].[Name]
    FROM [Products] AS [t0]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Orders] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ProductID] = [t1].[ProductID]
    ) AS [t2]
GROUP BY [t2].[ProductID], [t2].[Name]`